# Gathering all emails from table for email

Tags: php, mysql, email

I would like to build a webpage that follows the system in vBulletin of emailing.

So, currently, the user table contains the user data: username, userfullname, useremail etc.

Basically, what I need is for this script to gather the emails of the users from the database.

Additionally, I'd like the email to be sent out invididually, not as one bunch, in stages such as in vBulletin.

How would I go about this?

Comment: it sounds suspiciously like you're building a spam engine...

Comment: @MalphasWats: Most web applications have intensive emailing activity, just look at Facebook user notifications. Its an entirely valid question.

Comment: Thankls pablasso, MalphasWats, I'm building an intranet, and a function of it is to "be able to email all users"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could build a queue. Just enter those emails in a database and have a script running with cron every x minutes sending to those emails, the script should empty your queue each time it executes.

That way you can also avoid having to wait for the email function to end if you're executing in from a webpage